# The height of the text box cannot be changed on my website

Tags: wordpress, textbox, height

despite searching here on the forum, I can't find a solution to my textbox problem, which I can't shrink. If I manage to change it, after clicking it will enlarge again in the background and I need to reduce its height to 80px.

Can you advise me which class I should use to make the textbox really smaller? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you text box height is 80px if you want reduce that you have to change css

```
textarea.box_custom_size_class {
    max-height: 80px;
    resize: none;
    height: auto;
}
```

change max-height  value